# How to use t function from i18next outside of React Native component?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I try to use t function of i18next outside of React Native component. In some places I need to use "t" in function which is defined not in component. I don't know what would be the best way to pass the "t" into such functions.

Currently I'm thinking of these options:

- import "t" from i18n config file on top of the file where I want to use "t"
- use hook useTranslation() from 'react-18next' (not sure if this works if we use the hook not in component)
- also I can pass "t" as argument to the function , but this could be overcomplicating the function.

What option do you think is the simplest and the best?

So far I use useTranslation hook and sometimes importing "t" from i18n.js config file, but I need to stick to one method of importing "t".

Comment: in the mount of App.js , you can set window.t = t where the t can be from your hook.. then onwards wherever you need t, call it using window.t. (hook will not work outside react)

Comment: @manjs thanks for this method. But I think it's quite too much for this case. 

Also Im on React Native. Thing with window object won't work.

Comment: If the problem is window, I believe there is some alternative global is available in React native

Comment: @manjs don't know anything so far what it similar to window in RN. But I would avoid this way of doing if I were having this issue on the web. I used window rarely while doing the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the first option which works pretty well and don't add complexity to function's parameters

I personally do this inside utils files which do not contains any component:

```
import { t } from 'i18next';
export async function generateMailBody(user, isContact) {
  const yourMessage = isContact ? t('Your_message') : t('Problem_description');
  ...
}
```